# how to put an image to each button in use (for loop) in python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, photoimage

I want to create a loop to create several buttons, and put a different image in each button.
but it shows that on the last button,
-noted: when I run in (debug) step by step, it works.
-it's been two days since I search on google
thank you in advance

```
    from tkinter import *

    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("800x600")
    win.title("hhh")


    ls = ['/home/decode/Images/ImageDB/tom.png', '/home/decode/Images  /ImageDB/aub.png','/home/decode/Images/ImageDB/res.png']
    z=0
    #g= ls[z]


    for i in range(3):
        g= ls[z]
        img = PhotoImage(file=g)
        btn = Button(win, image=img)
        btn.pack()
        z+=1



    win.*mainloop*()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqPMM.png)``
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtBA7.png)

Comment: Study the iteration protocol. No index, no range, no `z` please

Comment: Are you sure your image file paths are correct? Why does one of them have spaces in it?

Comment: thank you for your reply
yes the path is good
when i do this 

'''
    from tkinter import *
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("800x600")
    win.title("hhh")

    ls = ['/home/decode/Images/ImageDB/tom.png', '/home/decode/Images/ImageDB  /aub.png','/home/decode/Images/ImageDB/res.png']

    im0 = PhotoImage(file=ls[0])
    im1 = PhotoImage(file=ls[1])
    im2 = PhotoImage(file=ls[2])

    btn0 =Button(win, image=im0).pack()
    btn1 =Button(win, image=im1).pack()
    btn2 =Button(win, image=im2).pack()

    win.mainloop()

'''

but I want to do that in a loop

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the PIL library and PhotoImage, for example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import* Image,Tkimage

win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x600")
win.title("hhh")

photo_1=PhotoImage(file=r'D:/button.png')

photo_image=Button(win,image=photo_1)
photo_image.place(x=10,y=0,height=12,width=12)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: PIL isn't required in this case. Modern versions of tkinte support png.